# Error in my XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm getting an error while trying to validate this piece of code... can anyone help me?

The program I use give little to no information on the problem, so if someone else can help me out I would be greatly appreciative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="tipusZone">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="district" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="neighborhood" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  
  <xs:complexType name="tipusObject">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent> 
  </xs:complexType> 
  <xs:complexType name="tipusGeo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="longitude" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="latitude" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent> 
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="tipusAddress">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="zone" type="tipusZone" />
      <xs:element name="geo" type="tipusGeo"/>
      <xs:element name="object" type="tipusObject"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  
  <xs:complexType name="tipusObra">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="issued" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="tipusAddress"/>
      <xs:element name="dtlastpub" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
  </xs:complexType> 
  <xs:element name="obres">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="obra" type="tipusObra" maxOcurrs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is missing the header.

Comment: @axus, no, it just wasn't formatted correctly.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop XSDs, you'll need to be able to locate any error messages provided by the tools you're using.

You should have seen a message along the lines of

> [Error] try.xsd:46:73: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOcurrs'
>   cannot appear in element 'element'.

and immediately realized that you simply had to correct `maxOcurrs` to be `maxOccurs` in order to fix your XSD.

There are no other (syntactical) problems with your XSD.